# How to round edges of particular faces where I have assigned emission material?

Tags: rendering, materials

hope you have a good day. I've stumbled upon a very specific problem, so hopefully, some of you will know the solution to this.

[image]

As you can see, I have selected faces of my model, to which I've assigned Emissive material through combination of nodes.

[image]

Well, I'm sure now you can easily see where this is going. The faces, which have the emissive material assigned, look pixelated and blocky. I have already searched for some solutions to this online, but haven't found any.

What I'm trying to achieve is to make these particular faces look less pixelated and more smooth. I know it can be achieved by rounding the outer edges of selection, but I don't know the workflow to this.

And yes - I have already tried beveling, only to find out it isn't of any use. I also tried to transform the outermost edges "To Sphere", but it didn't work either. How can this be done then? Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: I see two possible solutions: create a gradient that defines how the emissive material blends with the surrounding ones. See: [How can you smooth the edges between two materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials) or add a subsurf modifier, so that there is some form of interpolation on the materials. See [Material showing in wrong faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84158/material-showing-on-wrong-faces/84160#84160)

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How can you smooth the edges between two materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials)

Comment: A Smooth vertex could help you to smooth it. Smooth Vertex
Edit Mode
Tool Shelf ‣ Tools ‣ Mesh Tools ‣ Deform: Smooth Vertex

Comment: Hmm, it does not seem to do anything, LeoNas. The operator shows up and I'm asked to put in the amounts of smoothing, number of repeats, etc., but even after tweaking these settings, nothing seems to be happening. I have tried this method with outermost edges and even the whole selection, but without luck. 

cegaton thank you for your solution, I shall try it out. The only problem with respect to the discussion you posted is that my face selection is rather organic and unsymmetric, while his selection are just bands of rings.

Answer (score 1):

Better if you use a mix shader with a mask, instead of this method. Of course you can paint the emission pattern if you have a UV map.
[image]