# How do I stop my glass material from bleeding into the rest of the glass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

Hard to explain, so here are some pictures. (Blender 2.8 Cycles) I made the top section orange to better show what's going on.
Here's what's happening:
[image: bleedthrough]

Here is what I want to happen:
[image: You can see the effect in edit mode (it doesn't bleed there)]

Here are my current node setups:
[image: the bottom 85% of the cup should have a texture. The brick is just a placeholder texture for the time being.]
[image: the top 15% should be clear.]

I'm trying to model textures for a plastic soda cup, like the ones you see in restaurants.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Can you add a reference image of what you are trying to get?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=imgres&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiP8Yv5h5LhAhWOqZ4KHZx0DowQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homedepot.com%2Fp%2FCarlisle-20-oz-SAN-Plastic-Stackable-Tumbler-in-Clear-with-Coca-Cola-logo-imprint-Case-of-72-52203550A%2F204658596&psig=AOvVaw1h7qLd2LCw5mRDodMklO_5&ust=1553204258047516

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [material showing in the wrong faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84158/material-showing-on-wrong-faces/84160#84160)